# url not working after change apache port?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, port

Please help me to fix this problem!

I have installed xampp 5.6.12 on windows 8 ultimate. I cant'find the `"localhost/xampp/"` when ever i try it shows `"http://localhost//"` why ???

And I can show the page `"http://localhost/phpmyadmin"` also, several times i uninstall and install this "xampp" still its same , so i change `c:xampp\apache\conf\httpd` `"ServerName localhost:8080"` to( 80, 8800,8080) none of this work

so some one please help me !!! thank you???

Comment: instead of localhost/xampp/ try localhost/your-project-folder

Comment: Did you edit the HOSTS file to include `127.0.0.1 localhost` and `::1 localhost` If you didnt then `http://127.0.0.1` should work but `http://localhost` may not

Comment: Also if you change the `Listen` port from the default of 80 you will have to add that to the URL like `http://localhost:8080`

Answer (score 0):

i got my mistake ...

i used url like localhost:8081/program/factorial.php...

now its working fine i changed the port no 80 to 8081 and the problem resolved...